# Как закрепить стрелку?

Tags: javascript, html5

У меня есть шкала со стрелкой и 12 checkbox. При клике по checkbox, стрелка меняет своё положение (transform/rotate), но у меня не получается её закрепить. То есть, верх стрелки движется нормально, а нижняя её часть смещается. 
Изначально она в таком положении:[image: изначально]
А после выбора checkbox: [image: после]
Стрелка смещается, и я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы её нижняя часть не выходила за границу шкалы (или проще говоря: не смещалась вниз или другие стороны). Буду рад любой подсказке или помощи. Заранее благодарю!

```js
const COUNTER_STEP = 250;

class Checkbox {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.counter = 0;

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    const checkbox = e.target.closest('input[type="checkbox"]');

    if (!checkbox) return;

    this.isChecked(checkbox) ? this.decrease() : this.increase();
  }

  isChecked(checkbox) {
    return !checkbox.checked;
  }

  increase() {
    this.counter += COUNTER_STEP;
    document.querySelector('#arrow').style.transform = 'rotate(' + (-40 + ((this.counter * 70) / 1000)) + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = this.counter;
  }

  decrease() {
    this.counter -= COUNTER_STEP;
    document.querySelector('#arrow').style.transform = 'rotate(' + (-40 + ((this.counter * 70) / 1000)) + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = this.counter;
  }
}

new Checkbox(document.querySelector('.mainCont'));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 500;
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0 !important;
}
/* обёртка старт*/
.wrapp{
  width: 662px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
}
/* обёртка финиш*/

/* основные контейнеры старт */
header{
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainCont{
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.conAvat{
  width: 120px;
  height: 187px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
/* основные контейнеры финиш */

/* второстепенные контейнеры старт */
.inp{
  width: 79%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
.skills1{
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.skills2{
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.skills3{
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.meter{
  height: 250px;
}
/* второстепенные контейнеры финиш */

.conAvat img{
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 187px;
}
.inp input{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
  font-style: medium;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.inp img{
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 60px;
}
#ava{
  clip-path: circle();
}
.skls{
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#labell{
  color: #666666 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
.metImage{
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
/* стрелка и шкала старт*/
#arrow{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  transform-origin: center;
  left: 33%;
  top: 65%;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
#meter{
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 22px;
/* стрелка и шкала конец*/
}
p{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
hr{
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.count{
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
#counter{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #5392d4;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
 /* ///////////////////////////////// */
```

```html
<div class="mainCont" >
        <h5 class="skls">Навыки</h5>
        <div class="row skills1">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="html" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
              <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">HTML5</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
              <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">SASS</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3">
              <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">VANILLAJS</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col mr-3">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck4">
              <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4">GIT</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
      <div class="row skills2">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck5">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck5">CSS3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck6">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck6">LESS</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mr-1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck7">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck7">ANGULAR</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mr-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck8">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck8">FOUNDATION</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
      <div class="row skills3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck9">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck9">БЭМ</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck10">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck10">GULP</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mr-1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck11">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck11">JQUERY</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mr-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck12">
            <label id="labell" class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck12">BOOTSTRAP</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <hr>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <div class="row meter">
      <div class="col metImage float-left">
        <img id="meter" src="img/meter.png" alt="meter">
        <img id="arrow"src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
        </div>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
      <div class="col count float-right">
        <p>Мой уровень владения <br>Java Script</p>
        <label id="counter" for="">0</label>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вращать относительно центра круга, а не центра стрелки. Попробуй что-то такое подобрать:

```
transform-origin: right 10px;
```